# Postgres update with previous row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that records values from electrical meters

The table looks like this

```
SELECT created_at, value, delta 
FROM metervalues 
ORDER BY created_at

2013-05-28 07:59:00 | 752105,6 | null
2013-05-28 08:14:00 | 752156,0 | null
2013-05-28 08:29:00 | 752207,2 | null
2013-05-28 08:44:00 | 752259,2 | null
2013-05-28 08:59:00 | 752312,8 | null
2013-05-28 09:14:00 | 752366,4 | null
2013-05-28 09:29:00 | 752417,2 | null
```

now I want to calculate the consumption so

```
delta(current record) = value(current record) - value(previous record)
```

It could happen that records are added later so the record id's don't necessarily follow the "created_at" order.

Currently I'm loading the data using a ruby script then loop and update the records. This is very slow.

Can this be solved by SQL direct ? I tried some samples with cursors but did not really find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    created_at,
    "value",
    "value" - lag("value", 1, 0) over(order by created_at) as consumption
FROM metervalues
ORDER BY created_at
```

EDIT: Missing `as` before `consumption` -- now corrected

Comment: Hi,great, this works sofar, I only had to change the default (0) to 0.0 as value is a numeric field. How do I get the consumption updated to the records "delta" field

Comment: made it work! with new_values as (
SELECT
    id,
    created_at,
    "value",
    "value" - lag("value", 1, 0.0) over (order by created_at)  consumption
FROM metervalues
ORDER BY created_at)
update metervalues as mv set delta = new_values.consumption
from new_values
where mv.id = new_values.id;

Answer (score 3):

SQL tables are inherently unordered, so there is no "previous" record.  The question doesn't make sense, unless you have a column that specifies the ordering.

I think the question is saying that `created_at` is not such a column, but `RecordId` is.  If so, you can use the `lag()` function:

```
select created_at, value,
       (value - lag(value) over (order by recordId)) as delta
from metervalues
```

If you don't have such an id, then you need to find a way to specify the ordering of the values.

Comment: Hi, I know, that's why there is a "order by created_at" in the select statement in the sample above

Comment: @AlexanderMelle . . . Then just use `created_at` instead of `recordId` in the above query.